# npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json

Tags: docker, dockerfile, frontend, create-react-app, cicd

I need to install dependencies to build the frontend on CI/CD.

Dokerfile:

```
FROM node:18.12.1
enter code here
ENV CI="true"
WORKDIR /workdir
COPY package.json package-lock.json /workdir/
RUN npm ci
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "v2",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18next": "^21.9.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  ...
}
```

In container I faced with this errors:

```
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@6.12.6 does not satisfy ajv@8.12.0
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
...
```

Start on local environment works fine. How to fix this behavior?

I've tried remove `node_modules` and `npm install`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this problem because in my user settings (in `~/.npmrc`) the `legacy-peer-deps` flag was set to `true`, while it wasn't so in the build environment.

Comment: Oh my god, I have been struggling with this issue for several days, askign my coworker to checkout all my branches and fix my locks... This is the thing that I did not think about. Thanks so much

Comment: In case it helps someone, I had the same issue when deploying to App Engine in GCP, and managed to fix it by adding the legacy-peer-deps configuration in the project's package.json file

Answer (score 0):

It was my lockfile causing this problem. First of all, make sure you are on the correct version of Node (whatever that may be for you / your team)!

If you are willing to delete the lockfile (which can be a problem for obvious reasons) try this:

```
$ nvm use 16
Now using node v16.20.2 (npm v8.19.4)
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ rm package-lock.json
$ npm i
$ npm ci # should work
```

If you don't want to delete it then try this:

```
$ nvm use 16
Now using node v16.20.2 (npm v8.19.4)
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm i
$ npm ci # should work
```

If `npm ci` does not work then immediately run `npm i` again and then try `npm ci` again - hopefully it will work now!

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:18.12.1

ENV CI="true"

WORKDIR /workdir

# Remove package-lock.json
RUN rm package-lock.json

# Install npm dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package.json package-lock.json /workdir/

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . /workdir/

# Build your application
RUN npm run build

# Specify the command to run your application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks! It is works. But I need run `npm ci` on `CI/CD`. npm i Will make `package-lock.json` file different from the local environment

Comment: Can you please give me brief.

Comment: First check the ajv version in package.json and in package-lock.json file is same or not. If it founds deifferent in both file, try to delete package-lock.json file and again run npm install, it will create package-lock.json. Then try again to run npm ci. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I found out that the problem is with my local machine. I tried to build the project on another machine and there are package files.json and package-lock.json synchronized. Now I will try to reinstall nvm

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to someone. I ran into this problem because in my user settings(`~/.npmrc`) the `legacy-peer-dns` flag was set to `true`. I rolled back this settings to default value and now all works fine.  @poorvi-jain, thanks for trying to help.